# Conditional Where in Linq using query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a better way to have conditional where clauses in LINQ equivalent to the following?

```
var doGroup=false;
var doSub=true;
var query= from mydata in Data_Details
            where 
                ((doGroup && mydata.Group == "xxxx") || (doGroup==false)) &&
                ((doSub && mydata.SubGroup == "yyyy") || (doSub==false))
            select mydata;
```

In the code above that works it will optionally include 'Group' and 'SubGroup' depending on whether doGroup and doSub are true are false.

I know when using method syntax you can simply keep appending code to the query in separate lines but I'd prefer to keep using query syntax.

Comment: FYI, that's called query syntax.

Comment: i think you mean 'fluent' not 'fluid'

Comment: thanks I couldn't think of what linq syntax was called, and yes I did mean fluent. But what does Martin Fowler know, Fluid sounds better ;-)

Comment: I've always called it method syntax and that's what MS calls it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make this smaller is by optimizing the conditions themselves:

```
var doGroup=false;
var doSub=true;
var query=from mydata in Data_Details
                where 
                    (!doGroup || mydata.Group == "xxxx") &&
                    (!doSub || mydata.SubGroup == "yyyy")
                select mydata;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know whether there was a way to simply append to the query on multiple lines then call 'Select' as you would with the fluent interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}
```

Usage:

```
var doGroup =false;
var doSub = true;

var query = Data_Details
   .WhereIf(doGroup, q => q.Group == "xxxx")
   .WhereIf(doSub, e => e.SubGroup == "yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew about extension methods. I don't know why it was negged. But for my purpose I'll stick with the simpler way in this instance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruud Kobes answer is the right one, 
a small point at which there is not need to project data, 
last select is not needed.

```
var doGroup=false;
var doSub=true;
var query=from mydata in Data_Details
            where 
                (!doGroup || mydata.Group == "xxxx") &&
                (!doSub || mydata.SubGroup == "yyyy");
```